# Issue of getting data from two tables in web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i have created a simple API controller and added the following method in it:

```
public IQueryable<tbl_Book> GetBooks()
    {
        //AspNetUser user = new AspNetUser();
        return _context.tbl_Book;
    }
```

and then i have created an MVC controller to consume this API as follow:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<tbl_Book> books = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57368/api/");
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("Admin");
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<tbl_Book>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                books = readTask.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occured while fetching data from api");
            }
        }

            return View(books);
    }
```

it works just fine and gives the result but i want to get data from two tables which are tbl_Categories and AspNetusers which i do like this:

```
public IQueryable<tbl_Book> GetBooks()
    {
        //AspNetUser user = new AspNetUser();
        return _context.tbl_Book.Include(x=>x.AspNetUser).Include(x=>x.tbl_Category);
    }
```

book model has foreign keys from tbl_Categories and AspNetUsers but when i try to consume this above API with include functions it gives null result.

Comment: what is the status Code you are getting

Comment: Just for the record...you are using HttpClient wrong..   https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: It gives 500 internal server error

Comment: @Hackerman can you please tell me where i am wrong